Why is @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl not populated in HTTP call but works with Graph SDK?
I am trying to fetch the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl for items in a SharePoint list using a plain HTTP call to the Microsoft Graph API. However, the downloadUrl field is always returned as blank. Here is the HTTP request I am using:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=driveItem(select=id,contentType,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl)&$top=900

When I try the same request using the Microsoft Graph SDK, the downloadUrl is correctly populated:
var listItemsResponse = await graphServiceClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[documentList.Id].Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "driveItem" };
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "contentType" };
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 900;
});

bool hasDownloadUrl = driveItem.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl", out object? downloadUrl);



What's the expected behavior when you specified &Fields($select=Title) in the query? It's not a valid query parameter. expand=driveItem(select=id,contentType,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl) driveItem doesn't have contentType property

@user2250152 code updated. &Fields($select=Title) removed

@MannanBahelim Are you still getting blank results with that HTTP request? I got the response with downloadUrl populated correctly like this https://i.imgur.com/4WV4r0e.png.

@Sridevi I updated the image. I driveItem object still doesn't have downloadUrl. is it something related with the permission?

Note that, @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property won't be populated for SharePoint folders having content type as "Folder".
I have one SharePoint site having one folder and few files of different types as below:

When I ran HTTP request, @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property is not populated for  testfolder as it's ContentType is "Folder" as below:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/lists/listId/items?expand=driveItem(select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl)&$top=500

Response:

For remaining SharePoint files where ContentType is "Document", @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property will be populated in response like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/lists/listId/items?expand=driveItem(select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl)&$top=500

Response:

From your screenshot, you are not getting downloadUrl for drive item having ContentType as "Folder".
